# VBA y Nuevo Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, com

Supongo que más de uno ya habrá visto y probado la nueva versión de Outlook. Una interfaz distinta, funcionamiento algo distinto a la clásica versión y más sorpresas... Porque ahora no puede invocarse esta nueva versión desde VBA. Parece ser que esta versión no incluye el COM para poder comunicarnos mediante vba con Outlook.

Y esto es un problema, al menos para mi, que tengo automatizados ciertos procesos que a determinadas horas generan informes y reportes en Excel que se envían de forma automática en un equipo con Outlook. Y claro, el día que hagan el cambio definitivo a esa nueva versión, quiero estar preparado.

Por todo ello pregunto por aquí a los compañeros que usan VB/VBA si tienen el mismo problema y si se plantean alguna alternativa.

Muchas gracias.

Edito para ampliar info:

Ahora mismo tengo este código que genera el correo y lo envía tal que así:

```
Sub SendMailOutlook(Subject, TextBody, aTo, aCC, AttachYesNo, PathAttachments)
        
    Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Creo un nuevo mensaje
    olMailItem = 0
    Set Message = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With Message

    'Añado destinatarios, el cuerpo del mensaje, asunto y adjuntos.

    'Envío el correo
    .Send
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Ese método, con el nuevo Outlook no funciona. Al crear el objeto Outlook se ejecuta el Outlook de toda la vida, no el nuevo.

En mi caso no tengo posibilidad de crear ninguna herramienta, ni utilizar Grafana. Debería ceñirme a lo que tienen por defecto todos los equipos de la empresa: Office, VBA, vbscript, etc. De ahí que busque alguna alternativa para utilizar con lo que tengo.

Gracias.

Comment: No está claro tu escenario ¿Quien y como envía el correo?, ¿por qué necesitas outlook para enviar el correo? Pero incluso con esas clarificaciones, queda el tema que estas solicitando "alternativas" a un problema abstracto, básicamente un macro requerimiento. Te imaginas es listado enorme de alternativas posibles que existen para generar un excel y enviarlo por correo??? Esto hace que tu pregunta sea imposible de responder

Comment: Ambos llevais razón. Es cierto es que una pregunta amplia, aunque yo estoy nombrando VB/VBA y eso acotaría mucho las respuestas pues alguien podría decirme: tengo un código en vba en el que hago uso de X y me permite enviar correos con mi cuenta de empresa. 
Pero bueno, sé que esto no es el fin principal de SO y que este tipo de preguntas no son bien aceptadas. Gracias a ambos.

Comment: Muchas veces se dan ese tipo de respuestas en los comentarios, pero eso no quiere decir que la pregunta no deba ser cerrada. Yo no entiendo muy bien lo que estas haciendo, nunca lo he hecho de esa manera, antes creaba una pequeña aplicación para enviar reportes diarios, de esta manera no tenia que tener instalado office en el servidor. Actualmente eso tampoco lo hago, tengo mi propia herramienta de reportes vía web, en tu caso podrías usar algo como Grafana.

Comment: Ahora si tu quieres una respuesta especificas debes decir "Tengo este código en VBA" que genera un excel y lo envía de esta manera"  y luego agregar "Con la nueva versión de Outlook no me resulta, por este motivo, esto es lo que he intando para resolver el problema (pones tu código de intento)"

Comment: La pregunta del millon, porque abres Outlook en lugar de conectarte al servidor SMTP y mandar directamente el mail???

Comment: Pues porque no tengo claro que mi empresa me permita utilizar SMTP. Hace unos años caparon conexiones SMTP para usuarios de a pie y sólo permiten el correo web de la empresa (Outook Web) o la aplicación de escritorio. Por eso SMTP no era mi primera opción. No obstante, viendo las "ganas de ayudar" probaré esa opción antes de volver a escribir nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

No es que ese método no funcione con el nuevo Outlook, en general VBA no funciona con Outlook ya que no tiene compatibilidad con COM y Microsoft ya anunció que no la tendrá. Las alternativas son usar Power Automate, aunque Microsoft también ha anunciado que mejorará, en dicha versión de Outlook, la interacción con los complementos web. En resumen, lamentablemente ya no se podrá usar VBA por lo que no hay forma en que uses ese u otros códigos.

Comment: Que no tendrá compatibilidad lo sabía. Estos días he estado dándole una vuelta a como actuar y creo que no me quedará otra que meter de por medio Automate y Sharepoint/Onedrive. Al menos parece que el cambio no es inminente porque la nueva versión aún tiene bastante que mejorar y ciertos errores que solventar.

Comment: Esto es basciamente un comentario.. no entiendo ni la pregunta... es todo subjetivo.. tu respusta es tan buena como una que diga no se puede...